# Compare multiple vectors at the same time in R?

Tags: r, vector, logical-operators

I can easily compare 2 vectors in R to see how many elements are the same.
Say

```
  a<- c(1,2,3,4)
  b<- c(1,2,3,5)
  sum(a==b) would give me what I want
```

But how can I compare 3 vectors ? or more than 3 vectors at the same time ?

```
  a<- c(1,2,3,4)
  b<- c(1,2,3,5)
  c<- c(2,3,4,5)
  sum(a==b & b==c) # does not seem to be correct
```

I am looking for whether elements are same in the same position. In the same case, it would give me zero since a, b, c are not all the same at same position.

```
count = 0
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  if((a[i]==b[i]) & (a[i]==c[i]))
  count=count+1
} # this will give me that I want, but the efficiency seems very low
```

Comment: Are you looking for whether elements are same in the same position?  In that case comparing a,b,c, should give 0.  For example `a <- c(1,2,4,5);  b <- c(2,1,3,0) ; sum(a==b)#[1] 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
is.equal <- function(mylist) {

    check.eq <- sapply(mylist[-1], function(x) {x == mylist[[1]]})

    as.logical(apply(check.eq, 1, prod))                   

}

is.equal(list(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,2,5,4), c(1,1,3,4)))

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: it uses loops, so it should be slower of most of the solutions you could find for this problem. At least it works.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `matrix` or `data.frame` and check whether one of the `column` is equal to the rest.

```
 m1 <- cbind(a,b,c)
 sum(rowSums(m1==m1[,1])==ncol(m1))
 #[1] 0
```

Or

```
 sum(Reduce(`&`,Map(`==`, list(a,b,c), list(a))))
 #[1] 0
```

If you want to find the length of common elements,

```
 length(Reduce(intersect,list(a,b,c)))
 #[1] 2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I am trying to compare element by element comparison based on the data that the OP provided.  Suppose if I change `c <- c(1,3,2,4)`.  It would give `1`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I got confused by OP's description and the code `sum(a==b)`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to compare how many elements appear at the same position in 3 vectors. In the question, it would give 0.

Comment: @GeekCat In that case, the first option should work for you.  Keep all the vectors in a list and use `Reduce`